# Why is the outline of this <img> so much bigger than the actual picture?

Tags: html, css, web

[image: The outline of the img when using inspector in google chrome]

This button's height should ideally fill the white space sort of like the outlined blue, but for some reason does not fill up that space.

The code is:

```
 <button style="float:right !important; width:30%; background-color: transparent; background-size: 100%; border:0;" onclick="javascript:Store.cart.add(document.getElementById('cart_variation_id').options[document.getElementById('cart_variation_id').selectedIndex].value);return false;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qS50lMq.png" style="width:100%;display: block;">
    </button>
```

I know that css should probably be in a separate file, but right now I'm just trying to get it to look right first. Thank you!

Comment: You could use the `display:" "` css property.

Comment: The actual image is made on a canvas size larger than that of the image, its a png with a transparent background so unless you edit the image and take up all the canvas space you will probably need to change the position type of the image using css, maybe `absolute` and then move the other dom elements around it acordingly

Comment: Because, your image contain padding around it! Edit image and probably you will get expected result

Comment: Your image already filled the full space. But image have transparent are on all four side so, it looks like there is space. http://i.imgur.com/qS50lMq.png. There is no issue. Just change your image.And delete your question.

Answer (score 2):

Canvas size of the image is large.

Use this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnlDM.png

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle - your image takes full size of button box:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duu15hov/)

```
<body>
    <button style="float:right !important; width:30%; background-color: yellow; background-size: 100%; border:0; padding:0px;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/4sAOhQ4.png" style="width:100%;display: block;">
    </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The image is a png, which is an image format that allows for transparency.

[image: png with transparency in inspector]

See the gray and white checkerboard around the image? That is all transparent space that creates an invisible "border" around the button itself. Use an image editing tool to crop the image (or just use the image afelixj provided in his answer).